# displaying a loading cursor in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, xmlhttprequest

So I'm building an app to display photos that are taken by the user, and then uploaded to my FTP. Everything works just fine, but the images tend to take a while to sync from the server due their mobile data speed limitations. I'm fairly new at most of the js/phonegap stuff, so I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction. How would I display a loading cursor while it loads each image?

For my View Uploaded Photos, i have

/**
     * View pictures uploaded to the server
     */

```
function viewUploadedPictures() {

    // Get server URL
    server = document.getElementById('serverUrl').value;
    if (server) {

        // Get HTML that lists all pictures on server using XHR 
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

        // Callback function when XMLHttpRequest is ready
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4){

                // HTML is returned, which has pictures to display
                if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                    document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }

                // If error
                else {
                    document.getElementById('server_images').innerHTML = "Error retrieving pictures from server.";
                }
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", server , true);
        xmlhttp.send();         
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
navigator.notification.activityStart();
navigator.notification.activityStop();
```

You may also want to play with navigator.notification.loadingStart and
loadingStop which have snuck into the iPhone project.

Well as this is deprecated in version 0.9.5.1 so for > 0.9.5.1 you can consider to use

[jQuery BlockUI Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) .It's pretty configurable.

Comment: I read somewhere that was removed in 1.0.0, so I should stay clear of it.

Comment: :-O Yes its deprecated from 0.9.5.1

Comment: ok take a look at blockUi plugin.This may handy for you.Link is in my edited answer.